# Cannot copy contents of Wordpress directory to the web server root

Tags: linux, wordpress, debian, lamp

I'm a total newbie at this!
I have a virtual machine running Debian 9. I have LAMP installed. 
I am following the instructions at this link to install WordPress:
https://www.adminbyaccident.com/gnu-linux/how-to-install-wordpress-on-debian-9-lamp-stack/

I am now at this step:

We now copy the contents of the wordpress directory to the web server root.

```
albert@debian:~/wordpress$ sudo cp -a ~/wordpress/* /var/www/html
[sudo] password for albert:
albert@debian:~/wordpress$
```

However, when I try this (I don't use "sudo" because it's not installed on Debian by default), I get the following error message:

[image]
Someone please help me!!!
Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, I did that before performing all the commands. Again I followed the steps to the tee but when it came to to copying the wordpress directory I get the error that it can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the wordpress directory is not in the root directory.
Did you `cd` somewhere after downloading? If not, the wordpress dir should be at your current dir which is /home/lanalee/.
Type in `ls` to list all files in `/home/lanalee/`. If the list shows a directory named wordpress, you can continue with the following command:

```
cp -a ./wordpress/* /var/www/html
```

I replaced the `~` which points to your systems root directory with a `.` that refers to the folder your currently in.

If there is no wordpress directory listed, please type `ls ~/` and share the output with us.

Comment: OMG that worked. Thank you so much. You were the only person across three forums to respond with a solution that made sense. I am curious how the WordPress package got installed there instead of the system directory...? I logged in as a user, then I logged in as root user using "su". Regardless, I am very grateful to you. You rock!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)
When you login as a user, you're in the users home directory by default.
The su command does not change your directory, it only makes you operating as root user in the directory you logged in before.